# JavaScript looping issue in the middle of looping

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Hey guys I m trying to loop over the array of numbers, and what i want my function to do is whenever it is position of a number in array is EVEN number I want a program to return me 'Yan' word in stead of number. but when the position of a number is ODD number i want it to return just a number.

But for some reason in the middle of the array I am getting 'Yan' word instead of getting a number.

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]
const reversValid1 = valid1.reverse()

const myArray = []

const validateCard = (arr) =>{
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr.indexOf(reversValid1[i])%2 == 1){
            console.log('Yan')
        }
        else{
            console.log(arr[i])
        }
    }
}


validateCard(reversValid1)
```

I m getting the following response:

> 8
> Yan
> 8
> Yan
> 1
> Yan
> 8
> Yan
> 9
> Yan
> Yan
> Yan
> 9
> Yan
> 5
> Yan

You can see i m getting 3 Yan consecutively.

Comment: The specification is unclear, *whenever its position is even..* doesn't say much about numbers that occur multiple times in the input array.

Comment: indexOf returns the position of the first occurrence. If you want every even position as "YAN", you can simply check it with `i` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why instead of use `indexOf` don't use directly `i` ?

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]
const reversValid1 = valid1.reverse()

const myArray = []

const validateCard = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
      console.log('Yan')
    } else {
      console.log(arr[i])
    }
  }
}


validateCard(reversValid1)
```

The problem is `indexOf` will find multiple `index` of same number.

Example:

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8]
const reversValid1 = valid1.reverse()
for (let i = 0; i < reversValid1.length; i++) {
  console.log(reversValid1[i], reversValid1.indexOf(reversValid1[i]))
}
```

As you can see the same number have same index instead of index of array.

Comment: @Jamal have resolve your problem? can you acept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.forEach`:

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const reversValid1 = valid1.slice().reverse();

const validateCard = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach((v,i)=>{
    if (i%2 == 0) {
      console.log('Yan');
    } else {
      console.log(v);
    }
  });
};

validateCard(reversValid1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const reversValid1 = valid1.reverse();

const myArray = []

const validateCard = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
            console.log('Yan');
        }
        else {
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}


validateCard(reversValid1);
```

Or this:

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const reversValid1 = valid1.reverse();

const validateCard2 = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            console.log('Yan');
        }
        else {
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}

validateCard2(reversValid1);
```